# Change color of remaining buttons on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have 100 buttons on click of any button I want to change the color of remaining 99 buttons except the clicked button. How to achieve this? Adding click event handlers to all 100 buttons is NOT a good idea I guess. Please suggest me different ways of achieving this. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code in the question.

Comment: Is there an answer which helped you? Are you looking for any other intel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$('button').click(function() {
    $('button').css('background', 'red');
    $(this).css('background','none');
  });
});
```

It seems much easier

Answer (score 2):

What about this? (http://jsfiddle.net/nw77tgya/)

Off course you can flavour the code. You can replace the 'button' selector with a class selector to narrow your selection of buttons.

You can also change the css to add and remove classes and do other stuff.

This example should get you on the way though ;)

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$('button').click(function() {
    $('button').not($(this)).css('background', 'red');
    $(this).css('background','none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
<button>A Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain JavaScript solution.
What this does is it looks up all elements matching the selector supplied to `querySelectorAll`, loops through them, and if they're not the button that was clicked - the `e.target` - it sets their class to be something that you've styled somewhere.

If your buttons don't have classes:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.className = ''
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(b) {
    if (b !== e.target) {
      b.className = 'other-color' 
    }
  })
})
```

If your the original class is 'plain-button':

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.className = 'plain-button'
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.plain-button'), function(b) {
    if (b !== e.target) {
      b.className = 'plain-button other-color' 
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with vanilla JS, like this:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var clickedButton = this;
    [].forEach.call(buttons, function(innerBtn) {
      if (innerBtn !== clickedButton) {
        innerBtn.classList.add('green');
      }
      else {
        innerBtn.classList.remove('green');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

Or, in short jQuery:

```js
var buttons = $('button').click(function(){
  buttons.not(this).addClass('green');
  $(this).removeClass('green');
});
```

```css
.green {
  background:green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Buttons in **HTML** and add a `class-name` or `new attribute` to make easier for writing `selector` in **Jquery**.

```
<button class="test">button1</button>
<button class="test">button2</button>
<button class="test">button3</button>
```

Select all the elements in **Jquery** by defining the `selector` and add the CSS to all elements **except** the current element.
For making it work on second click, we should **reset** the CSS of the current element

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    $(this).css( "background-color", "" );
    $( ".test" ).not( $(this) ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```